google Pie chart
I need to do a half pie chart with 7 values, but it isn't working, the graph isn't showing all values
my chart is like this, but it isn't showing properly and the pointer isn't working

function exibirChart(obj) {
    // Configurações padrão do gráfico
    let configuracoes = {
        containerId: 'containerChartMetas',
        totalProduzido: 0,// Total produzido
        metaComissao: 0,// Meta 1
        metaBonus: 0,// Meta 2
        meta3: 0, // Meta 3
        nivel0: 0,// Nível 0 não atingiu a meta
        nivel1: 0,// Nível 1 não atingiu a meta
        nivel2: 0,// Nível 2 não atingiu a meta
        nivel3: 0,// Nível 3 não atingiu a meta
        valorMaximoTotal: 100, // Valor máximo total
        valorMinimoTotal: 0,// Valor mínimo total
        espessuraPonteiro: 2,// Espessura do ponteiro
        cores: { // Cores do gráfico
            abaixoMeta: '#ff6c6c', /*vermelho*/
            metaComissao: '#dee083', /*verde claro Meta 1*/
            metaBonus: '#97cd7e', /*verde medio Meta 2*/
            meta3: '#64bd7b', /*verde escuro*/
            nivel3:'#faea81',/*amarelo */
            nivel2:'#ffb17a',/*laranja */
            nivel1:'#f79171',/*salmão */
            nivel0:'#f96a6e',/*vermelho claro */
            ponteiro: '#3a3a3a'
        },
        legendas: {// Legendas do gráfico
            abaixoMeta: '',
            metaComissao: '',
            metaBonus: '',
            meta3: '',
            nivel0: '',
            nivel1: '',
            nivel2: '',
            nivel3: '',
        },
        ...obj
    }

    // Adiciona classe 'show' ao contêiner do gráfico
    $('#' + configuracoes.containerId).addClass('show');
    if (configuracoes.metaBonus === 0 && configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal === 0 && configuracoes.meta3 === 0) {
        configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal = configuracoes.metaComissao * 1;
        configuracoes.meta3 = configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal;
    } else if (configuracoes.meta3 === 0 && configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal === 0 && configuracoes.metaBonus > 0) {
        configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal = configuracoes.metaBonus * 1;
        configuracoes.meta3 = configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal;
    } else if (configuracoes.metaComissao > configuracoes.metaBonus) {
        $('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .container-chart').html('<div class="alert bg-danger text-white">O valor da meta 2 precisa ser maior do que o valor da meta 1.</div>')
        return false;
    } else if (configuracoes.metaComissao > configuracoes.meta3) {
        $('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .container-chart').html('<div class="alert bg-danger text-white">O valor da meta 3 precisa ser maior do que o valor da meta 1.</div>')
        return false;
    } else if (configuracoes.metaComissao > configuracoes.metaBonus) {
        $('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .container-chart').html('<div class="alert bg-danger text-white">O valor da meta 2 precisa ser maior do que o valor da meta 1.</div>')
        return false;
    }

    // Calcula a espessura do ponteiro
    const espessuraPonteiro = (configuracoes.espessuraPonteiro * configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal) / 100;

    /*Valores dos niveis abaixo das metas*/
    let totalParcial = 0;
    totalParcial = (configuracoes.metaComissao) / 4;
    /*Valores dos niveis abaixo das metas*/

    // Inicializa o contador
    let contador = configuracoes.valorMinimoTotal;

    // Define o intervalo para atualização do gráfico
    const intervalo = setInterval(function () {
        contador += configuracoes.totalProduzido / 3;

        // Verifica se o contador atingiu o total produzido
        if (contador >= configuracoes.totalProduzido) {
            contador = configuracoes.totalProduzido;
            clearInterval(intervalo);
        }

        // Calcula o percentual do valor atual em relação à meta de comissão
        const valorPercentual = contador * 100 / configuracoes.metaComissao;
        const stringPercentual = valorPercentual.toFixed(1).replace('.', ',') + '%';

        // Atualiza as informações no HTML
        $('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .chart-valor-percentual').text(stringPercentual);
        $('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .chart-valor-minimo').text('R$ ' + parseInt(configuracoes.valorMinimoTotal).toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));
        $('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .chart-valor-maximo').text('R$ ' + parseInt(configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal).toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));

        // Array de configuração para o gráfico
        let arrayConfig = new Array();
        let colorObject = new Object();

             arrayConfig = [
                ['Status', 'Valor'],

                //Abaixo Metas
                [configuracoes.legendas.nivel0, configuracoes.metaComissao],
                [configuracoes.legendas.nivel1, configuracoes.metaComissao],
                [configuracoes.legendas.nivel2, configuracoes.metaComissao],
                [configuracoes.legendas.nivel3, configuracoes.metaComissao],

                //calculo Meta Comissao
                [configuracoes.legendas.metaComissao, configuracoes.metaBonus - configuracoes.metaComissao],
                //calculo Meta Bonus
                [configuracoes.legendas.metaBonus, configuracoes.meta3 - configuracoes.metaBonus],

                [(contador - configuracoes.meta3 > (configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal - configuracoes.meta3) / 3 ? configuracoes.legendas.meta3 : ''), configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal - configuracoes.meta3],

                //Ponteiro
                ['', espessuraPonteiro],

                [(contador - configuracoes.meta3 <= (configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal - configuracoes.meta3) / 3 ? configuracoes.legendas.meta3 : ''), 0],

                ['', configuracoes.valorMaximoTotal]
            ];

        colorObject = {
                    //Abaixo Metas
                0: { color: configuracoes.cores.nivel0 },
                1: { color: configuracoes.cores.nivel1 },
                2: { color: configuracoes.cores.nivel2 },
                3: { color: configuracoes.cores.nivel3 },
                    //Meta1
                4: { color: configuracoes.cores.metaComissao },
                    //Meta 2
                5: { color: configuracoes.cores.metaBonus },
                    //Meta 3
                6: { color: configuracoes.cores.meta3 },
                    //Ponteiro
                7: { color: configuracoes.cores.ponteiro },
                8: { color: 'transparent' }
            }
        

        // Desenha o gráfico
        google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayConfig);

            var options = {
                title: '',
                pieHole: 0.45,
                legend: 'none',
                pieSliceText: 'none',
                pieStartAngle: 270, // Ângulo inicial do gráfico
                slices: colorObject,
                pieSliceBorderColor: 'transparent',
                chartArea: { left: 0, top: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%' },
                fontSize: 16,
                fontName: 'Poppins',
                enableInteractivity: false,
                backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' },
            };

            // Instancia e desenha o gráfico
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.querySelector('#' + configuracoes.containerId + ' .chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    }, 20)
}`

I don't know what to do to read the values and insert in the chart with the correct proportion for each color
